# Coq extending judgemental equality on Ensemble

Tags: coq

I am stuck with proving something like this

```
Theorem EqualContainIn (A: Type) (x: Ensemble A) (y: Ensemble A) (X: Ensemble (Ensemble A)) : forall eq: (Same_set A x y),  (X x) -> (X y).
```

In essence I want `Same_set` to be treated as judgemental equality on `Ensemble` is it possible to do that in Coq?

Comment: Doesn't that make `Same_set` only a propositional equality, not judgemental? I think "judgemental equality" means the type checker can actually identify the two, without us having to manually apply any coercion like `EqualContainIn`.

Comment: Yea, I meant, is it possible to make propositional equality as judgemental equality?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, there is an `Extensionality_Ensembles` axiom in the Ensemble completely missed that. Though, is it possible for a language to directly support something like that instead of we defining them as an axiom?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.